# Building in a new toggle button to Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app that was created awhile ago and I'm trying to add a new feature to it.

You will notice there are two datasets that one can toggle back and forth with called `C4` and `C3`. What I'm trying to do is add a third dataset that one can toggle between called `NAM`. You might also notice that certain filters are removed when you toggle between `C4` and `C3` (as seen in the screenshots). For example: `C3` has the option of using `Partisan Range` but that isn't an option for `C4`. Adding this new dataset (`NAM`) would be somewhat similar. The goal would be to remove both the Turnout and Partisan "Range" sliders when you select `NAM` (but every other filter would remain).

I'm just having some issues embedding the new dataset into the Shiny tool without messing up the previous iteration.

**EDIT based on YBS response: What I’m noticing is that while switching to NAM correctly removes, something still needs to be done on the server side. For example: Let’s say you open the app, select State as PA, set County as “All,” set City as “PITTSBURGH,” move the age slider to between 18 and 35 and don’t touch the turnout and partisan sliders - both remain between 20 and 80. Set to “C4” it correctly shows a size of 0. Switch it to C3 and it correctly shows a size of 0. But when you switch it to “NAM” it also says 0, which is incorrect. It should be 1. What I believe is happening is that when you switch to NAM, it’s just taking how the turnout and partisan sliders are set to under C4 and filtering the data. If you go back and move those two sliders to be between 0 and 100 and then switch back to NAM, it correctly displays 1. How can we fix that so that the results when you switch to NAM are independent from those sliders?**

Here is the `server.R` file:

```
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  mydf <- reactive({get(input$mydata)})
  observeEvent(input$data1, {
    df <- mydf()
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(C4$county[C4$state %in% input$data1]))))
  }, priority = 2)
  
  observeEvent(c(input$data1, input$data2), {
    req(mydf())
    df <- mydf()
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(C4$city[C4$county %in% input$data2]))))
    } else {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(C4$city[C4$state %in% input$data1]))))
    }
  }, priority = 1)
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    req(input$data1,input$data2,input$data3,input$data4,input$data5,input$data6,input$turnout,input$age[1])
    temp_data <- mydf()
    if (sum("All" %in% input$data1)<1) {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$state %in% input$data1, ]
    }
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$county == input$data2, ]
    }
    if (sum("All" %in% input$data3)<1) {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$city %in% input$data3, ]
    }
    if (input$data4 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$demo == input$data4, ]
    }
    if (input$data5 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$registration_status == input$data5, ]
    }
    if (input$data6 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$vb_voterbase_mailable_flag == input$data6, ]
    }
    
    df2 <- temp_data %>% dplyr::filter(age >= input$age[1] &
                                         age <= input$age[2] &
                                         turnout_score >= input$turnout[1] &
                                         turnout_score <= input$turnout[2])
    if (input$mydata=="C4") df2 <- df2 %>% dplyr::filter(partisan_score >= input$partisan[1] & partisan_score <= input$partisan[2])
    
    df3 <- if (is.null(input$phones)) df2 else df2 %>%  dplyr::filter(!is.na(phone))
    df3
  })
  
  output$universecount <- renderPrint({
    universecount <- paste("Universe Size:", nrow(filtered_data()))
    
    universecount
    
  })
  
}
```

And here is the `UI.R` file **Which includes @YBS edit**:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Builder"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("mydata", label = "C4 or C3 or NAM?", choices = c("C4","C3", "NAM"), inline=TRUE),
      selectizeInput("data1", "Select State", selected = "MI", multiple = TRUE, choices = c(unique(sort(C4$state)))),
      selectizeInput("data2", "Select County", choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("data3", "Select City", selected = "DETROIT", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
      selectizeInput("data4", "Select Demo", choices = c("All", unique(sort(C4$demo)))),
      selectizeInput("data5", "Select Registration Status", choices = c("All", unique(sort(C4$registration_status)))),
      selectizeInput("data6", "Valid Address", choices = c("All", unique(sort(C4$vb_voterbase_mailable_flag)))),
      sliderInput("age", label = h3("Select Age Range"), 18,
                  35, value = c(18, 20), round = TRUE, step = 1),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.mydata=='C4' || input.mydata=='C3'",
                       sliderInput("turnout", label = h3("Select Turnout Range"), min = 0, max = 100, value = c(20,80))
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.mydata=='C4'",
                       sliderInput("partisan", label = h3("Select Partisan Range"), min = 0, max = 100, value = c(20,80))
      ),
      prettyCheckboxGroup("phones", h3("Only Include Valid Phone Numbers?"), selected = "Yes", choices = list("Yes")),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("universecount"),
      tags$head(tags$style("#universecount{color: red;
                                 font-size: 32px;
                                 font-style: italic;
                                 }"
      )
      )
    )
  ) 
)
```

If it helps, here are sample datasets for each:

```
    C4 <- structure(list(state = c("PA", "MI", "PA", "NC", "WI", "TX", 
    "TX", "NC", "NC", "NC", "PA", "MI", "NC", "AZ", "TX", "PA", "PA", 
    "TX", "TX", "TX", "TX", "WI", "TX", "WI", "MI", "TX", "TX", "MI", 
    "NC", "PA", "TX", "AZ", "TX", "PA", "AZ", "NC", "AZ", "WI", "TX", 
    "NV", "NC", "AZ", "TX", "TX", "AZ", "WI", "NC", "TX", "NV", "MI"
    ), city = c("PHILADELPHIA", "SPARTA", "GLEN CAMPBELL", "CHARLOTTE", 
    "MARSHFIELD", "HUMBLE", "MANVEL", "MORRISVILLE", "CHARLOTTE", 
    "BURLINGTON", "PITTSBURGH", "MONROE", "MOORESVILLE", "MARANA", 
    "LITTLE ELM", "PHILADELPHIA", "CHEYNEY", "AUSTIN", "AUSTIN", 
    "DALLAS", "ALAMO", "ALGOMA", "TEMPLE", "RACINE", "MIDLAND", "PLAINVIEW", 
    "AUSTIN", "EAU CLAIRE", "CHARLOTTE", "SHARPSVILLE", "HURST", 
    "GLENDALE", "MCALLEN", "ABINGTON", "KLAGETOH", "CHARLOTTE", "TOLLESON", 
    "KENOSHA", "EL PASO", "HENDERSON", "TAYLORSVILLE", "MESA", "FORT WORTH", 
    "SUGAR LAND", "GILBERT", "GENOA", "HENDERSONVILLE", "EDNA", "LAS VEGAS", 
    "MARLETTE"), county = c("PHILADELPHIA", "KENT", "INDIANA", "MECKLENBURG", 
    "MARATHON", "HARRIS", "BRAZORIA", "DURHAM", "MECKLENBURG", "ALAMANCE", 
    "ALLEGHENY", "MONROE", "IREDELL", "PIMA", "DENTON", "PHILADELPHIA", 
    "DELAWARE", "TRAVIS", "TRAVIS", "DALLAS", "HIDALGO", "KEWAUNEE", 
    "BELL", "RACINE", "MIDLAND", "HALE", "TRAVIS", "BERRIEN", "MECKLENBURG", 
    "MERCER", "TARRANT", "MARICOPA", "HIDALGO", "MONTGOMERY", "APACHE", 
    "MECKLENBURG", "MARICOPA", "KENOSHA", "EL PASO", "CLARK", "ALEXANDER", 
    "MARICOPA", "TARRANT", "FORT BEND", "MARICOPA", "VERNON", "HENDERSON", 
    "JACKSON", "CLARK", "SANILAC"), age = c(35L, 33L, 24L, 33L, 31L, 
    24L, 33L, 26L, 21L, 28L, 31L, 30L, 35L, 31L, 30L, 34L, 29L, 35L, 
    28L, 35L, 31L, 33L, 24L, 33L, 20L, 21L, 29L, 23L, 32L, 31L, 21L, 
    35L, 24L, 24L, 33L, 34L, 23L, 28L, 29L, 22L, 22L, 29L, 29L, 33L, 
    30L, 28L, 26L, 22L, 34L, 26L), demo = c("Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
    "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "African-American", "Uncoded", 
    "Caucasian", "African-American", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
    "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Uncoded", "Caucasian", 
    "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
    "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Caucasian", "African-American", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "African-American", "Hispanic", 
    "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
    "Hispanic", "Asian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Hispanic", 
    "Caucasian", "Caucasian"), turnout_score = c(53.2, 21.2, 8.7, 
    57.6, 52.9, 8.7, 10.5, 13.9, 3.7, 26, 6.1, 9.2, 8.2, 7.6, 12.2, 
    8.4, 2.5, 8, 8.2, 5.4, 24, 4.8, 3.3, 57.4, 44.2, 4.8, 5.2, 37.5, 
    48.1, 35.1, 16.3, 18.8, 2, 22.2, 67.5, 71.6, 14.3, 85.2, 1.7, 
    51.1, 14.5, 32.2, 13.3, 18.1, 52, 26.7, 41.3, 8.6, 52.4, 3.3), 
        partisan_score = c(95.8, 25.5, 44.8, 98, 31.7, 96.7, 82.8, 
        82.5, 91.1, 1, 94.8, 12.1, 25.6, 6.3, 35.4, 99, 98.6, 67.4, 
        13, 55.7, 44.2, 34.9, 53.8, 68.5, 24, 76.7, 94, 41.4, 96.7, 
        93.6, 69.6, 89.9, 43.2, 3.8, 99.1, 98.2, 98, 92.2, 42.6, 
        97, 92.1, 73.4, 68.7, 83.7, 10.6, 29.7, 98.7, 49.4, 97.9, 
        30.3), phone = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
        NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
        NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), registration_status = c("Registered", 
        "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
        "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
        "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Unregistered", 
        "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
        "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
        "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
        "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
        "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
        "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
        "Registered", "Registered", "Unregistered", "Registered", 
        "Registered"), vb_voterbase_mailable_flag = c("Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
        "", "Yes", "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -50L))

C3 <- structure(list(state = c("PA", "PA", "PA", "TX", "NC", "TX", 
"PA", "PA", "TX", "NV", "TX", "PA", "MI", "PA", "NC", "AZ", "TX", 
"TX", "MI", "WI", "TX", "NC", "TX", "PA", "TX", "MI", "PA", "NC", 
"NV", "NV", "AZ", "PA", "NC", "TX", "MI", "TX", "NC", "TX", "TX", 
"TX", "PA", "PA", "MI", "TX", "MI", "MI", "TX", "TX", "TX", "MI"
), city = c("PHILADELPHIA", "WARFORDSBURG", "PITTSBURGH", "SLATON", 
"WAYNESVILLE", "KATY", "PUNXSUTAWNEY", "BROOKHAVEN", "LAREDO", 
"LAS VEGAS", "SEALY", "ROSTRAVER TOWNSHIP", "DETROIT", "SWISSVALE", 
"RALEIGH", "YUMA", "PFLUGERVILLE", "LAGUNA VISTA", "WHITEHALL", 
"FRANKSVILLE", "CEDAR PARK", "WINSTON SALEM", "ABILENE", "WILKES BARRE", 
"WACO", "WARREN", "LEETSDALE", "WILLOW SPRING", "HENDERSON", 
"CARSON CITY", "MESA", "HARRISBURG", "WILLOW SPRING", "AUSTIN", 
"BIRMINGHAM", "HOUSTON", "JACKSONVILLE", "ROCKWALL", "AMARILLO", 
"CONROE", "WARMINSTER", "RED LION", "BELDING", "CEDAR HILL", 
"NEW ERA", "CHARLEVOIX", "HORIZON CITY", "BRYAN", "DALLAS", "GRAND RAPIDS"
), county = c("PHILADELPHIA", "FULTON", "ALLEGHENY", "LUBBOCK", 
"HAYWOOD", "FORT BEND", "JEFFERSON", "DELAWARE", "WEBB", "CLARK", 
"AUSTIN", "WESTMORELAND", "WAYNE", "ALLEGHENY", "WAKE", "YUMA", 
"TRAVIS", "CAMERON", "MUSKEGON", "RACINE", "WILLIAMSON", "FORSYTH", 
"TAYLOR", "LUZERNE", "MCLENNAN", "MACOMB", "ALLEGHENY", "WAKE", 
"CLARK", "CARSON CITY", "MARICOPA", "DAUPHIN", "WAKE", "TRAVIS", 
"OAKLAND", "HARRIS", "ONSLOW", "ROCKWALL", "POTTER", "MONTGOMERY", 
"BUCKS", "YORK", "IONIA", "DALLAS", "OCEANA", "CHARLEVOIX", "EL PASO", 
"BRAZOS", "DALLAS", "KENT"), age = c(32L, 29L, 25L, 26L, 32L, 
24L, 25L, 35L, 30L, 30L, 35L, 27L, 30L, 25L, 29L, 21L, 35L, 31L, 
25L, 35L, 20L, 24L, 21L, 27L, 27L, 33L, 19L, 22L, 22L, 33L, 21L, 
27L, 21L, 31L, 35L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 24L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 34L, 
30L, 24L, 30L, 35L, 20L, 25L), demo = c("African-American", "Caucasian", 
"African-American", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Hispanic", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Hispanic", "Caucasian", "Hispanic", "Caucasian", 
"African-American", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Hispanic", "Caucasian", 
"Hispanic", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "African-American", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "African-American", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Hispanic", 
"Hispanic", "Caucasian", "Caucasian"), turnout_score = c(7.6, 
30.9, 6.6, 2.6, 59.4, 1.9, 17.6, 2.4, 51.7, 25.4, 1.5, 2.9, 13.1, 
6.9, 26.9, 35.5, 19.2, 30.8, 18.9, 55.2, 11.6, 17.9, 6.8, 1.4, 
6.9, 29.1, 25.7, 4, 44.7, 30.9, 67.5, 26.6, 25.6, 1.3, 58.8, 
1.4, 18.6, 19.2, 4.1, 7.6, 8.2, 16.7, 18.6, 7.4, 3.1, 41.7, 2.4, 
18.1, 8.5, 74.8), partisan_score = c(98.4, 1.2, 98.5, 60, 0.5, 
73.3, 0.7, 6.8, 93.3, 0.7, 33.3, 72.2, 96.3, 98.1, 92.1, 98.1, 
64.1, 78.7, 40.5, 6.3, 61.1, 98.1, 77.4, 95.9, 57.6, 36, 3.3, 
98.8, 32.5, 1.5, 72.6, 1, 5.3, 76.2, 42.6, 82.9, 67.2, 36.3, 
77.3, 18, 97.2, 27.5, 33, 72.4, 47.8, 65.3, 44.9, 86.4, 69.6, 
98.2), phone = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), registration_status = c("Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered"), vb_voterbase_mailable_flag = c("No", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))

NAM <- structure(list(state = c("TX", "WI", "NV", "MI", "PA", "MI", 
"MI", "NC", "PA", "PA", "NC", "PA", "NV", "TX", "NC", "TX", "MI", 
"WI", "TX", "PA", "PA", "NV", "PA", "TX", "NV", "TX", "TX", "PA", 
"TX", "TX", "MI", "PA", "PA", "PA", "TX", "MI", "NC", "PA", "PA", 
"PA", "TX", "NC", "AZ", "NC", "TX", "TX", "PA", "TX", "PA", "NC"
), city = c("SAN JUAN", "BROOKFIELD", "RENO", "CENTRAL LAKE", 
"PITTSBURGH", "SOUTHFIELD", "CLIO", "GREENSBORO", "BLAKESLEE", 
"CRESSONA", "FAYETTEVILLE", "DOYLESTOWN", "SPARKS", "RICHARDSON", 
"GARNER", "COPPERAS COVE", "TAYLOR", "HILBERT", "ODESSA", "HATBORO", 
"MC KEES ROCKS", "LAS VEGAS", "PHILADELPHIA", "LAREDO", "HENDERSON", 
"AZLE", "LEAGUE CITY", "COLLEGEVILLE", "GARLAND", "HOUSTON", 
"DEARBORN HEIGHTS", "PITTSBURGH", "PHILADELPHIA", "LANCASTER", 
"AZLE", "TRENTON", "MIDDLESEX", "PHILADELPHIA", "ACME", "ALTOONA", 
"LUFKIN", "ASHEVILLE", "TEMPE", "CHAPEL HILL", "BANDERA", "HUTTO", 
"DOWNINGTOWN", "ARLINGTON", "DILLSBURG", "GASTONIA"), county = c("HIDALGO", 
"WAUKESHA", "WASHOE", "ANTRIM", "ALLEGHENY", "OAKLAND", "GENESEE", 
"GUILFORD", "MONROE", "SCHUYLKILL", "CUMBERLAND", "BUCKS", "WASHOE", 
"DALLAS", "JOHNSTON", "CORYELL", "WAYNE", "CALUMET", "ECTOR", 
"MONTGOMERY", "ALLEGHENY", "CLARK", "PHILADELPHIA", "WEBB", "CLARK", 
"PARKER", "GALVESTON", "MONTGOMERY", "DALLAS", "HARRIS", "WAYNE", 
"ALLEGHENY", "PHILADELPHIA", "LANCASTER", "PARKER", "WAYNE", 
"JOHNSTON", "PHILADELPHIA", "WESTMORELAND", "BLAIR", "ANGELINA", 
"BUNCOMBE", "MARICOPA", "ORANGE", "BANDERA", "WILLIAMSON", "CHESTER", 
"TARRANT", "YORK", "GASTON"), age = c(25L, 35L, 33L, 28L, 30L, 
28L, 28L, 32L, 32L, 35L, 28L, 23L, 29L, 29L, 34L, 33L, 23L, 30L, 
35L, 22L, 32L, 25L, 33L, 19L, 24L, 21L, 31L, 21L, 35L, 20L, 26L, 
28L, 26L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 28L, 23L, 21L, 32L, 30L, 27L, 24L, 
27L, 19L, 31L, 31L, 19L, 35L), demo = c("Hispanic", "Caucasian", 
"African-American", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "African-American", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "African-American", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Other", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Uncoded", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "African-American", "Hispanic", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Asian", "Hispanic", "Caucasian", "African-American", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "African-American", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", "Caucasian", 
"Uncoded", "Caucasian", "Caucasian"), turnout_score = c(11.5, 
92.2, 25.5, 80.2, 19.8, 80.8, 9.5, 38.6, 21.7, 64.9, 6.3, 24.1, 
41.7, 79.8, 43.9, 28.2, 11.8, 84.1, 12.6, 70.4, 48.4, 7.6, 80.2, 
15, 60.9, 44.8, 8.5, 51.7, 44.9, 42.4, 83.7, 84, 72.5, 76.3, 
9.9, 82.2, 41.9, 9.1, 14.8, 51.8, 82.5, 34.7, 93.7, 46.1, 16.8, 
32.7, 4.2, 83.3, 27.5, 7.6), partisan_score = c(55.6, 58.9, 5.5, 
97, 1.2, 98.6, 71.7, 94.3, 96.4, 94.8, 93.7, 16.8, 24.3, 98.8, 
4.1, 29.6, 30.4, 20.9, 36, 98.6, 83.4, 23.1, 99.1, 63.4, 62.2, 
34.1, 79, 98.5, 75.6, 75.8, 92.8, 98.9, 98.7, 0.9, 77.7, 97.5, 
97, 88.1, 96.3, 2, 1, 90.3, 97.3, 78.9, 11.7, 64.9, 95.8, 99.8, 
7.6, 2.7), phone = c(1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 
1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), registration_status = c("Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered", 
"Registered", "Registered", "Registered", "Registered"), vb_voterbase_mailable_flag = c("Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(sqldf)

# C4 <- C4 %>% mutate(state = as.character(state), city = as.character(city), county = as.character(county), demo = as.character(demo), registration_status = as.character(registration_status), vb_voterbase_mailable_flag = as.character(vb_voterbase_mailable_flag))
# C3 <- C3 %>% mutate(state = as.character(state), city = as.character(city), county = as.character(county), demo = as.character(demo), registration_status = as.character(registration_status), vb_voterbase_mailable_flag = as.character(vb_voterbase_mailable_flag))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Builder"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("mydata", label = "C4 or C3 or NAM?", choices = c("C4","C3", "NAM"), inline=TRUE),
      selectizeInput("data1", "Select State", selected = "MI", multiple = TRUE, choices = c(unique(sort(C4$state)))),
      selectizeInput("data2", "Select County", choices = NULL),
      selectizeInput("data3", "Select City", selected = "DETROIT", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
      selectizeInput("data4", "Select Demo", choices = c("All", unique(sort(C4$demo)))),
      selectizeInput("data5", "Select Registration Status", choices = c("All", unique(sort(C4$registration_status)))),
      selectizeInput("data6", "Valid Address", choices = c("All", unique(sort(C4$vb_voterbase_mailable_flag)))),
      sliderInput("age", label = h3("Select Age Range"), 18,
                  35, value = c(18, 20), round = TRUE, step = 1),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.mydata=='C4' || input.mydata=='C3'",
                       sliderInput("turnout", label = h3("Select Turnout Range"), min = 0, max = 100, value = c(20,80))
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.mydata=='C4'",
                       sliderInput("partisan", label = h3("Select Partisan Range"), min = 0, max = 100, value = c(20,80))
      ),
      prettyCheckboxGroup("phones", h3("Only Include Valid Phone Numbers?"), selected = "Yes", choices = list("Yes")),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("universecount"),
      tags$head(tags$style("#universecount{color: red;
                                 font-size: 32px;
                                 font-style: italic;
                                 }"
      )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  mydf <- reactive({get(input$mydata)})

  observeEvent(mydf(), {
    df <- mydf()
    mins <- min(df$age)
    maxs <- max(df$age)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "data1", "Select State", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$state))))
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "data4", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$demo))))
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "data5", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$registration_status))))
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "data6", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$vb_voterbase_mailable_flag))))
    updateSliderInput(session,"age",min=mins, max=maxs, value=c(max(18,mins),min(35,maxs)))
  })

  observeEvent(input$data1, {
    df <- mydf()
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "data2", "Select County", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$county[df$state %in% input$data1]))))
  }, priority = 2)

  observeEvent(c(input$data1, input$data2), {
    req(mydf())
    df <- mydf()
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$city[df$county %in% input$data2]))))
    } else {
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "data3", "Select City", server = TRUE, choices = c("All", unique(sort(df$city[df$state %in% input$data1]))))
    }
  }, priority = 1)

  filtered_data <- reactive({
    req(mydf(),input$data1,input$data2,input$data3,input$data4,input$data5,input$data6,input$turnout,input$age[1])
    temp_data <- mydf()
    if (sum("All" %in% input$data1)<1) {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$state %in% input$data1, ]
    }
    if (input$data2 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$county == input$data2, ]
    }
    if (sum("All" %in% input$data3)<1) {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$city %in% input$data3, ]
    }
    if (input$data4 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$demo == input$data4, ]
    }
    if (input$data5 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$registration_status == input$data5, ]
    }
    if (input$data6 != "All") {
      temp_data <- temp_data[temp_data$vb_voterbase_mailable_flag == input$data6, ]
    }

    df2 <- temp_data %>% dplyr::filter(age >= input$age[1] & age <= input$age[2])
    if (input$mydata %in% c("C4","C3")) df2 <- df2 %>% dplyr::filter(turnout_score >= input$turnout[1] & turnout_score <= input$turnout[2])
    if (input$mydata=="C4") df2 <- df2 %>% dplyr::filter(partisan_score >= input$partisan[1] & partisan_score <= input$partisan[2])

    df3 <- if (is.null(input$phones)) df2 else df2 %>%  dplyr::filter(!is.na(phone))
    df3
  })

  output$universecount <- renderPrint({
    universecount <- paste("Universe Size:", nrow(filtered_data()))

    universecount
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I believe you forgot the Server side.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like it's not quite right though. Please see the comment I made in the edits (bold) before I can close this out.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing I'm noticing though. When you switch to `NAM`, changing the age range slider appears to have no impact on filtering the results. So if you set State, County, and City to "All" and don't change anything else, it should show 18. But then if you slide the age range down, it doesn't appear to have any impact on the data filtering, which is incorrect.

Comment: Please try the updated code.